# what does this means? 'In this folder make sure your shell is bash or a derivative and run fix-it-all.sh.'

Tags: command-line

I am following the steps to install a simulator Disksim, please let me know the meaning of this line. What i actually need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything to your Ubuntu installation, you will have bash as your default shell. You can make sure with the command `ps`.

Then `cd` into this directory and there run the indicated shell script:

```
cd given_directory
./fix-it-all.sh
```

Comment: I tried this but when i run 'fix-it-all.sh'. It says command not found. @muclux

Comment: Did you type it with the beginning './' and did you do the 'cd' before as I wrote? Then check the permissions of ./fix-it-all.sh and eventually do `chmod +x fix-it-all.sh` before running it.

Comment: Yes i did 'cd' first. When i wrote it with './' it says 'no such file or directory' and when i did without this it says 'command not found'.

Comment: Then please add the output of `ls -l given_directory` and `ls -ld given_directory`to your question (replacing of course 'given_directory' by the directory in your original question.